# How to save current_user email and show it to the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am making rails blog and I want to make functionality where comment author can be anonymous or current_user depending of if its signed in or not.

How can I save current_user email and show it to the user? I guess I didn't connected user and comment properly?

When I try to save comment, I get user must exist error. When I set user_id manually, @commenter is empty.

This is comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @user = current_user if user_signed_in?
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user
      @user.id = current_user.id
      @user.comments.build(comment_params)
      @commenter = @user.email
    end

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfuly created comment!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
  end
end
```

I have this in partial and it doesn't work, why??

```
<%= @commenter %>
```

As for models: Comment belongs_to User and Post. User and Post has_many comments.

This is show.html.erb for post where comment partial is rendered:

```
...
<%= render @post.comments %>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about it is not working? Are you getting an error, is it just not showing up, also can you post the view this partial is located in?

Comment: Just updated question ;)

Comment: Where is you show action for comments?

Comment: I don't need one because comments are rendered in posts view

Comment: Ok will then then your problem is possibly there, you should post that controller as well.

Comment: Can you please post the associations between your User, Post and Comment models?